# What is a "mail order record"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I encountered this term in the following text of this [article about Sir Richard Branson](https://jamesclear.com/successful-people-start-before-they-feel-ready) by James Clear:

> Four years later, he was looking for ways to grow his small magazine and started selling **mail order records** to the students who bought the magazine. The records sold well enough that he built his first record store the next year. After two years of selling records, he decided to open his own record label and recording studio.

I especially have trouble with the meaning of **record** here: Usually, a record is something done with a camera or something similar. However, this does not make much sense here, at least not for me.

Could you please explain the meaning and the context in this text? Thank you!

Comment: Since you have found your understanding of *record* doesn't fit, what have you looked up in a dictionary or two? I'm really surprised that the mention of *record store* and *record label* wasn't enough to make [sense 4](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/record) the obvious choice. I must be getting old.

Comment: Here is [a picture of a record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LP_record#/media/File:12in-Vinyl-LP-Record-Angle.jpg). It contains music.

Comment: Did you look up the definition of "record"?

Comment: I must be living in the future...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *record* is this case used to be a common name for what is now known as "vinyl" or "vinyl records". Vinyl records preceded digital, CD and cassette media as a means of listening to music. They were hugely popular in the 20th century.

A *record store* was where one would buy records. Some trivia: Sir Richard Branson's first record store was on Oxford Street, London. It opened in 1971.

"Mail order records" are records bought via mail order.

[image: record]

Comment: +1.  I hope you don't mind, I added a picture.

Comment: Thanks, the image helps. BTW didn't know about 10 inch records!

Comment: @suspectus Most 78rpm records were (are) 10" diameter.

Comment: You have never heard the Aerosmith song "My Big Ten  Inch" ?